# 14:04 Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi. Module cgid already enabled

Tags: 14.04, server, apache2

I tried to use CGI in my ZoneMinder in my Ubuntu Server, but according to this [Documentation](http://www.zoneminder.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Server_14.04_64-bit_with_Zoneminder_1.28.0_the_easy_way) CGI is not enabled in Ubuntu 14.04 by default. For I enable I have to use a2enmod cgi but it returns this error for me

```
# a2enmod cgi
Your MPM seems to be threaded. Selecting cgid instead of cgi. Module cgid already enabled
```

How can I enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually three distinct messages in that response:

- Your MPM seems to be threaded.
- Selecting cgid instead of cgi.
- Module cgid already enabled

What the message is saying is that:

- the **cgi** module is not compatible with your Apache installation, but the **cgid** module performs the exact same thing and is compatible with your apache installation, so..
- it will use **cgid** instead,
- but **cgid** it's already enabled, so it doesn't need to do any work

If your **cgi** directory isn't being served, try restarting apache